# failed to bind data to dropdownlist in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net to build my website.
I'm trying to bind data to dropdownlist that found in my gridview.
When I'm trying to connect that data to dropdownlist I'm getting nullreference.
what can be the problem?

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="TauluGridcompetitors" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Weapon">
                         <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="NoWeaponDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Short Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Long Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dual Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<string> competitors = Request.Cookies["TauLucompetitors"].Value.ToString().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
            TauluGridcompetitors.DataSource = competitors;
            TauluGridcompetitors.DataBind();
            GridView temp = (GridView)this.FindControl("TauluGridcompetitors");
            **DropDownList DDL1 = (DropDownList)TauluGridcompetitors.FindControl("NoWeaponDDL");**
            DDL1.DataSource = BindXml("XML/NoWeapon.xml");
            DDL1.DataTextField = "Type";
            DDL1.DataValueField = "ID";
            DDL1.DataBind();
        }
    }


    private DataSet BindXml(string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = "~/" + fileName;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        return ds;
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: where is the error ocurring? Have you checked what data is in the data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind data to dropdownlist in **RowDataBound** event and use **ItemTemplate** instead of **EditItemTemplate**.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="TauluGridcompetitors" OnRowDataBound="TauluGridcompetitors_RowDataBound" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Weapon">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="NoWeaponDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Short Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Long Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dual Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group Weapon"></asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> competitors = Request.Cookies["TauLucompetitors"].Value.ToString().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
        TauluGridcompetitors.DataSource = competitors;
        TauluGridcompetitors.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void TauluGridcompetitors_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{     
    DropDownList DDL1;         
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DDL1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("NoWeaponDDL");
        DDL1.DataSource = BindXml("XML/NoWeapon.xml").Tables[0];
        DDL1.DataTextField = "Type";
        DDL1.DataValueField = "ID";
        DDL1.DataBind();
    }
}

private DataSet BindXml(string fileName)
{
    string filePath = "~/" + fileName;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(filePath));
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: this line is still null: DDL1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("NoWeaponDDL"); even when i used this code in the RowDataBound event.

Comment: hi,@liorko, it's because that you use **EditItemTemplate** instead of **ItemTemplate**,so it can not be found in the default mode ItemTemplate.I edited my answer,try it again.